# Query taking too much time

Tags: mysql, performance, subquery, execution-plan, query-performance

My query is taking too much time to execute. Please help me here.

```
mysql> explain 
select pcm.catalog_id 
from cat_produ_catal_map_defer pcm, cat_catal_catal_map_defer ccm, cat_catal_defer c  
where 
    pcm.product_id = 2520000  
    and ccm.catalog_id = pcm.catalog_id 
    and ccm.parent_catalog_id = 1000025 
    and levels <> 0 
    and c.catalog_id = pcm.catalog_id 
    and c.precedence is not null 
order by c.precedence;
+----+-------------+-------+------+--------------------------------------------+----------+---------+------------------------+------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys                              | key      | key_len | ref                    | rows | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+--------------------------------------------+----------+---------+------------------------+------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c     | ALL  | idx_1031,idx_17109                         | NULL     | NULL    | NULL                   | 2769 | Using where; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | pcm   | ref  | idx_2195,idx_1069                          | idx_2195 | 10      | cms.c.catalog_id,const |    1 | Using where; Using index    |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ccm   | ref  | idx_2902,idx_651,fkey_cat_catal_catal_4433 | idx_2902 | 10      | cms.c.catalog_id,const |    1 | Using where                 |
+----+-------------+-------+------+--------------------------------------------+----------+---------+------------------------+------+-----------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)


mysql> show create table cat_produ_catal_map_defer\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: cat_produ_catal_map_defer
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `cat_produ_catal_map_defer` (
  `row_mod` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `row_create` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `catalog_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `idx_2195` (`catalog_id`,`product_id`),
  KEY `idx_1069` (`product_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fkey_cat_produ_catal_3725` FOREIGN KEY (`catalog_id`) REFERENCES `cat_catal_defer` (`catalog_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fkey_cat_produ_catal_3763` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `cat_produ_defer` (`product_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_bin
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show create table cat_catal_catal_map_defer\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: cat_catal_catal_map_defer
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `cat_catal_catal_map_defer` (
  `row_mod` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `row_create` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `catalog_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_catalog_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `levels` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `idx_2902` (`catalog_id`,`parent_catalog_id`),
  KEY `idx_651` (`levels`),
  KEY `fkey_cat_catal_catal_4433` (`parent_catalog_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fkey_cat_catal_catal_3688` FOREIGN KEY (`catalog_id`) REFERENCES `cat_catal_defer` (`catalog_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fkey_cat_catal_catal_4433` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_catalog_id`) REFERENCES `cat_catal_defer` (`catalog_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_bin
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show create table cat_catal_defer\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: cat_catal_defer
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `cat_catal_defer` (
  `row_mod` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `row_create` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `catalog_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prod_result_changes_callback` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `inheritance_mode` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `datafile_regexp` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_change_callback` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `add_category_callback` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `delete_category_callback` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `root_category_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `precedence` varchar(20) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `idx_1031` (`catalog_id`),
  KEY `idx_1709` (`root_category_id`),
  KEY `idx_17109` (`precedence`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_bin
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: This is not 100% related to the question but what's the purpose of having nullable unique keys? Especially because you have foreign keys that reference these nullable columns?

Answer (score 5):

The core issue appears to be that the optimizer does not (or cannot) use the index `idx_17109` to seek for the `c.precedence IS NOT NULL` predicate. The following modification allows the seek, but still requires a hint to avoid the sort:

```
SELECT
    pcm.catalog_id 
FROM cat_catal_defer AS c USE INDEX (idx_17109)
JOIN cat_produ_catal_map_defer AS pcm ON
    pcm.catalog_id = c.catalog_id
JOIN cat_catal_catal_map_defer AS ccm ON
    ccm.catalog_id = pcm.catalog_id
WHERE
    c.precedence > ''
    AND pcm.product_id = 2520000
    AND ccm.parent_catalog_id = 1000025
    AND ccm.levels <> 0
ORDER BY
    c.precedence;
```

Explain:

[image: Explain table]

Try [the SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/85268/27).

Answer (score -2):

"Using filesort" sounds bad.

Your request take its time on the sorting step, do you really need to sort your result set ?

Try to remove the ORDER BY, to validate that the problem comes from here.

Max.